# How can I avoid being redirected to a local google domain in Selenium Chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, google-search, browser-automation

When I'm opening google.com and doing a search in Chrome Selenium WebDriver, it redirects me to my local google domain, although the search string I'm using is "google.com ....." How can I remain on the "com" domain?

Answer (score 2):

Use this url - `https://www.google.com/ncr`. This will not redirect to your location specific site.